# Javascript function not working with html5 + Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am doing as suggested in  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I have used Flask + HTML5 + JS

Flask project directory structure is:

```
Flask /
      Flask.py
      static /
              js / Flask.js
              styles / Flask.css
      templates / Flask.html
```

I have included the Flask.js in Flask.html as below, in all possible places (in top, bottom, out of `<head>`, etc) of html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/Flask.js"></script>
```

When I put all the code in html file as mentioned in the link above, everything works well, but when I separate out the js part to Flask.js in the structure above, it doesn't work.

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong or if you need any additional information.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `src="/static/js/Flask.js"` ??

Comment: What do you mean by "but when I separate out the js part to Flask.js"? Do you mean you write `src="static/Flask.js"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use `url_for` helper function:

```
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/Flask.js') }}"
```

to link your static files.

Comment: Thanks @doru, That worked! One more thing that the statement should be out of <head></head>